# Change the url with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to create multilingual links to my site, i wat thinking of using str_replace, but im not sure if this is the right choice. Maybe REGEX would do the trick... However im not that fluent in regular expressions...

My urls are like this:
localhost/project/public/LANG/event/id/

The LANG can be:

```
/en/ 
/fi/
/sv/
```

The urls are the same otherwise, just the /LANG/ part of the url changes.
I have tried to change the url with this:

```
<?php
$search = array("/sv/", "/fi/");
$replace = array("/en/");
$url_en = str_replace($search, $replace, $url);
echo $url_en;
?>
```

However that does not give me the right url, and it replaces all things with sv or fi. I think the correct solution would be

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka That is not true as you can see below ;-)

Comment: this things are done using the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .htaccess file to translate the frindly urls

create a .htaccess file in your root website directory

your links will look like domain/a/b/c/d

localhost/project/public/LANG/event/id/

this is being translated as domain/index.php?action=project&saction=public&language=LANG&taction=event&tid=id

they are being translated by this file into domain/index.php?action=a&id=b&saction=c&sid=d

below is one of my files, as example; good luck

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(producator)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&producator=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(producator)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&producator=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(producatorx)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&producatorx=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(producatorx)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&producatorx=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(tag)/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=tag&tag=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(update)-([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&saction=update&code=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(delete)-([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&saction=delete&code=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&saction=$3&sid=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=details&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not doing -1 because of your low rep, but did you just dump one of the .htaccess file you are using somewhere? I see no relation with what was being asked in Question, and what you answered. Question was about changing urls to include one of EN, FI, SV etc, but you are talking about producator, actions. Either modify your answer to address the question, or people will downvote it..

Comment: he has to replace some of the words and he has to catch the idea; how his links look like, how they must be translated; i think that this is the right way to resolve all his problems with links

Comment: But even then dumping down 13+ lines of Pure htaccess on someone, without any explanation of each line is like saying `Hey You!!, look here, pick what you want and go away! Good Luck.`Anyways, it was just my opinion and you are for sure free to answer in any way you want.

Comment: No, sorry, I am still having trouble wrapping my head around ReGex in .htaccess

Answer (score -3):

```
preg_replace('|(localhost/project/public/)..|', '\1EN', $url);
```

Comment: use the htaccess file and establish all the urls structures; this is very usefull because if a url structure is matched, you know all the variables and values